# In which language is F#'s compiler written?

Tags: f#

In which language is F#'s compiler written?

I've heard that F#'s compiler is written in F# :)
(each next version of F# compiler is written on its previous version)
But:
1. Can't google if it's true.
2. If it's true, in which language is the first version of the F# compiler written?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The F# compiler is written in F#.  The source code is [available](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp).

It was originally bootstrapped years ago using OCaml, I believe (and perhaps a little C++ as well).  (There is still a non-trivial subset of F# that cross-compiles with OCaml, though the F# compiler source base has long since diverged from that.)

The current implementation always uses an LKG (last-known-good) set of binaries (.NET DLLs and EXEs) to bootstrap itself when building from source.

Comment: If by 'convoluted' you mean 'standard procedure for all self-hosted compilers', then yes!  :)